# Power Shell marquee progress bar not working

Tags: winforms, powershell

What I'm attempting to do is create a window using forms and add a marquee style progress bar that continuously loops while my script runs. I'm not concerned about tracking progress, it is just so the user knows that something is occurring.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$window = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$window.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(400,75)
$window.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$window.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$window.Text = "STARTING UP"

$ProgressBar1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$ProgressBar1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(365, 20)
$ProgressBar1.Style = "Marquee"
$ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 20
$window.Controls.Add($ProgressBar1)

$window.ShowDialog()
```

This draws the progress bar and the window, but I don't get the marquee animation inside the progress bar.

What am I missing?

Comment: It works for me.  What version of powershell are you running?

Comment: Marquee style is only supported on Windows XP or Windows 2003 Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm running powershell version 2.0. I'm on Windows 7. What other type of progress bar style is available that I can use to achieve what I'm attempting?

Comment: This lists the valid options for the `Style` attribute. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

VisualStyles must be enabled. That's why on ISE works, but doesn't on Console.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$window = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$window.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(400,75)
$window.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$window.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$window.Text = "STARTING UP"

$ProgressBar1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$ProgressBar1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(365, 20)
$ProgressBar1.Style = "Marquee"
$ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 20
$window.Controls.Add($ProgressBar1)

$window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU Davidtgbe !! I have been searhing for the last three hours trying to find why a marquee scroll would work in ISE, but not when called from batch. I added your "EnableVisualStyles()" and it's working 100% correctly. It's helped me towards a deadline I have.