# ProgressBar shows on ISE but not on Console. Powershell responsive GUI on Runspace

Tags: powershell, user-interface, progress-bar, responsive, runspace

I've been working on a simple proof of concept / template of a script in which I have the default Runspace to run heavy tasks and another one to run a responsive GUI.

I have tested various methods to be able to communicate the runspaces. At first I tried the Control.Invoke but some opinions on different forums and a weird behaviour on tests led me to use a message based intercomunication based on a Synchronized HashTable. ProgressBar works with control.Invoke, but, executing some other actions, like disabling multiple buttons on a form performs very slow.

1st problem: I would like to show a progressbar (marquee) when the task is executing, changing its visible state. However, the progressbar is showed when the script runs on ISE, but not when it does on console. I think it is because main runspace is busy, but I don't understand how it could affect the GUI runspace...

2nd: on the script I post below, I'm using scriptblocks through a stack variable to pass the commands between runspaces. Then, each runspace (main runspace does it through pooling and GUI through a timer) checks if a task is pending of execution in the stack, and, if so, executes it. However if I would want to call a function declared on the other runspace (Test-OutOfMainScopeUiFunction in this example), I couldn't. I would get a runtime error on the scriptblock. I have thought solutions to this like:
-Importing functions on both runspaces
-Making functions global or use functon delegates¿?
-Passing a string with the commands to execute in spite of a scriptblock -> Using this one at the moment, but don't like very much... error prone

Any solution to the progress bar problem or script improvements will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
$global:x = [Hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$global:x.MainDispatcher = new-object system.collections.stack
$global:x.UiDispatcher = new-object system.collections.stack
$global:x.GuiExited = $false

$formSB = { 

  [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
  [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

  Function Test-OutOfMainScopeUiFunction 
  {
    $x.Host.Ui.WriteLine("Test-OutOfMainScopeUiFunction Executed")
  }
  Function Execute-OnMainRs
  {
    param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock
    )

    $x.Host.Ui.WriteLine("`r`nAdding task")

    $x.MainDispatcher.Push($ScriptBlock)

    $x.Host.Ui.WriteLine("Task added")
    $x.Host.Ui.WriteLine("Task: $($x.MainDispatcher)")
  }

  $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

  $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $button.Text = 'click'
  $button.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Right

  $progressBar = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar)
  $ProgressBar.Style = [System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle]::Marquee
  $ProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50
  $ProgressBar.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Bottom
  $ProgressBar.Visible = $false  

  $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $label.Text = 'ready'
  $label.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Top

  $timer=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
  $timer.Interval=100

  $timer.add_Tick({
      if($x.UiDispatcher.Count -gt 0)
      {
        & $($x.UiDispatcher.Pop())
      }
  })

  $form.Controls.add($label)
  $form.Controls.add($button)
  $form.Controls.add($progressBar)

  Add-Member -InputObject $form -Name Label -Value $label -MemberType NoteProperty
  Add-Member -InputObject $form -Name ProgressBar -Value $progressBar -MemberType NoteProperty

  $button.add_click({ 
      Execute-OnMainRs -ScriptBlock {
          write-host "MainRS: Long Task pushed from the UI started on: $(Get-Date)"
          start-sleep -s 2
          write-host "MainRS: Long Task pushed from the UI finished on: $(Get-Date)"
        }
  })

  $form.add_closed({ $x.GuiExited = $true })

  $x.Form = $form

  $timer.Start()

  $form.ShowDialog()

}

Function Execute-OnRs
{ 
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock
  )

  $x.Host = $Host

  $rs = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
  $rs.ApartmentState,$rs.ThreadOptions = "STA","ReUseThread"
  $rs.Open()
  $rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("x",$x)

  $ps = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock)

  $ps.Runspace = $rs
  $handle = $ps.BeginInvoke()

  #Almacenar variables del RS
  $x.Handle = $handle
  $x.Ps = $ps
}
Function Execute-OnUiRs
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock
  )

  $x.UiDispatcher.Push($ScriptBlock)
}

Function Dispatch-PendingJobs
{ 
  while($global:x.GuiExited -eq $false) { 
    if($global:x.MainDispatcher.Count -gt 0)
    {
      Execute-OnUiRs -ScriptBlock {
        $msg = "UIRS: MainThread informs: Long Task started on $(Get-Date)."
        $global:x.Form.Label.Text = $msg
        $global:x.Form.ProgressBar.Visible = $true
        $x.host.ui.WriteLine($msg)    
        #Next line throws an error visible on UI runspace error stream
        Test-OutOfMainScopeUiFunction
      }

      & $($global:x.MainDispatcher.Pop())

      Execute-OnUiRs -ScriptBlock {
        $msg = "UIRS: MainThread informs: Long Task finished on $(Get-Date)."
        $global:x.Form.Label.Text = $msg
        $global:x.Form.ProgressBar.Visible = $false
        $x.host.ui.WriteLine($msg)
      }

      write-host "UI Streams: $($global:x.Ps.Streams |out-string)"
    }
    else
    {
      start-sleep -m 100
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the same problem. Copy and pastecode into ISE and works. On powershell, doesn't:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294292/power-shell-marquee-progress-bar-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution... http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/enabling-visual-styles

VisualStyles must be enabled first. The problem is not related with runspaces stuff. This is a brief and clearer code example taken from [Power Shell marquee progress bar not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294292/power-shell-marquee-progress-bar-not-working) with the fix.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$window = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$window.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(400,75)
$window.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$window.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri",11,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$window.Text = "STARTING UP"

$ProgressBar1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$ProgressBar1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(365, 20)
$ProgressBar1.Style = "Marquee"
$ProgressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 20
$window.Controls.Add($ProgressBar1)

$window.ShowDialog()
```